# What's the issue in this smarty code?

Tags: foreach, smarty

I can't get what's the issue in below smarty code?

```
<select class="list_items" name="staff_id" id="staff_id">
                  <option value="">All</option>
                    {if $staff_details}
                      {foreach from=$staff_details item=$staff_info}
                  <option value="{$staff_info.staff_id}"  {if $staff_id==$staff_info.staff_id} selected="selected"{/if}>{$staff_info.staff_full_name}</option>
                      {/foreach}
                    {/if}  
                  </select>
```

The assigned $staff_details array is as follows:

```
Array
(
    [staff_id] => ff8d4a5ea6bf11dce105aa2fa7b959b8
    [staff_type_id] => 2
    [staff_full_name] => Chetan G
    [staff_email] => admin@gmail.com
    [staff_password] => 123456
    [staff_status] => enable
)
```

It's giving me the error:

```
Fatal error: Smarty error: [in chapter-mcq-questions.tpl line 45]: syntax error: 'foreach: 'item' must be a variable name (literal string) (SmartyCompiler.php, line 1183) in /var/www/schooling_needs/core/libs/Smarty.php on line 1095
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of

```
{foreach from=$staff_details item=$staff_info}
```

do

```
{foreach from=$staff_details item=staff_info}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it worked for me, but when i go through foreach array it's giving me only the first letter of each array element. Actually I want a whole value e.g. Staff full name from array. Can u help me in getting this? Thanks one again.

Comment: well if you make your array into something like this `Array
(
  [0] => array (
    [staff_id] => ff8d4a5ea6bf11dce105aa2fa7b959b8
    [staff_type_id] => 2
    [staff_full_name] => Chetan G
    [staff_email] => admin@gmail.com
    [staff_password] => 123456
    [staff_status] => enable
  )
)`
It should work but right now yo don' ahve the key you're trying to look for
to make it easier to see just echo $staff_info

Comment: Yes you are right, but I'm new to smarty can you help me to create the array in this way?

Comment: I'm sorry, I've never used smarty so I really don' have any idea of how to do it but I'm guessing you could find it pretty fast on google ;)